# Not able to restore weights on batch size 1 from a saved model of higher batch size for predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I want to use the model now for prediction purposes. The batch size which is used throughout the model can be configured before training, but now for prediction purposes, I want my batch size to be 1 and I want to use the saved model which is trained on a different batch size (16). I tried restoring the model on batch_size 1, but it gave the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,75] rhs shape= [1,16,75]
```

What are the ways that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I supposed you used defined shape in your input placeholders. In this case you can first load meta graph (in case if you saved that), and then create new placeholders of new shapes and add them to this graph.

But the better way to resolve this problem is to change your batch_size value in your placeholders to None. This will mean that later you can feed any batch size input to your NN. e.g.:

```
x_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32,32,3], name='InputData')
y_target = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name='LabelData')
```

Comment: The only placeholder used in all the code is: `handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])`